# Custom role based authorization from an existing database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Currently, I am developing an web application in ASP.net and till now i have done authenticating the user after successful login using Identity in ASP.Net. Now i want to authorize the user based on the different roles available in the database. I have a database with 3 tables namely Users, Roles and UserRoles. A user can have more than 1 role.
In this case, how can i implement role based authorization in my project.I have done custom authentication using Identity and removed Entity from my project.

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the custom user manager and custom signin manager to use a single instance per 
        request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomUserManager>(CustomUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<CustomSignInManager>(CustomSignInManager.Create);
    }
```

With this, simple`[Authorize]` attribute is working fine for me. How can i create something like `[Authorize(Roles="Customer")]`? Should i use something like IRole for this or just overriding Authorize Attribute method is enough? Is both same or different? Can anyone help me to solve this problem?